# How can I create a program that will count clicks in a PDF and transfer that to Excel?

Tags: excel, pdf

It's been a while since I've written code, so please excuse my shortcomings. I do construction estimation and one of the most time consuming parts is counting items on a PDF (the PDF does not always have a tag or remark where I have an item I need to count.) When I find the item on the PDF, I note the room number and item that I find in Excel. I was wondering how I could create a program that would allow me to screenshot the PDF, click items on the page, and keep count of each different item in excel or, export to excel. 
My experience has been in C++ and VB but its been 15 years since I've written much code, and I've played in python, so if anyone has any suggestions I'd be happy to hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Daemonstalker so, if I understand you right, you want to have a short way to click on information in a PDF and have it send the information about the item you clicked on the PDF to an excel spreadsheet so you can keep track of it.

Short answer is no. A PDF is basically an image itself, there's nothing simple you can program to parse an item you click on into any usable form of data that could be exported to an excel spreadsheet.

If there's no text about the item you are wanting to keep track of, what information do you want to keep track of in your spreadsheet?

If there is any text about the item you want to keep track of why couldn't you just highlight the information you want to keep track of, copy it and paste it into a spreadsheet?

[image]

Anything more complex than that would require some pretty hefty programming to do, which if you haven't coded for 15+ years would take quite a bit of effort for you to accomplish. The law of diminishing returns would apply, you would have to weigh how much time it would take you to get up to speed and build your program against how much time it would actually save you over time.

Hope this helps!